# Deleting related rows with laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to delete all related rows in Laravel with:

```
$customers = Customer::find($clientId);
$customers->delete();
$customers->locations()->delete();
$customers->locations->objects()->delete();
$customers->locations->objects->subscriptions()->delete();
$customers->locations->objects->history()->delete();
```

And also tried:

```
$customers = Customer::find($clientId);
$customers->delete();
$customers->locations()->delete();
$customers->locations()->objects()->delete();
$customers->locations()->objects()->subscriptions()->delete();
$customers->locations()->objects()->history()->delete();
```

Laravel deletes the customer and locations but does not delete the objects, subscriptions and history and trows an error.

What can I do to delete them too?

EDIT: I changed the order like this:

```
$customers = Customer::find($clientId);
$customers->locations()->objects()->subscriptions()->delete();
$customers->locations()->objects()->history()->delete();
$customers->locations()->objects()->delete();
$customers->locations()->delete();
$customers->delete();
```

and get the error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::objects()`

Comment: have you tried deleting related model first and then parent model?

Comment: @Anik I use soft deletes, it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: what error did it throws?

Comment: I think that would be problem, because when you do $customers->locations()->delete() it tries to find out location of customers which are not deleted (in your case, it use deleted_at is NULL) and deleted_at is not NULL when you already deleted customer.

Comment: @AgeDeO Can you confirm if you have added objects function as relation in location model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to override delete method in model to delete all related objects for each location 
and also delete should be in order, so first delete objects, then locations and then customer. for ex.

```
$customers = Customer::find($clientId);
$customers->locations()->delete();
```

now for delete location override delete method in you model something like

```
class Location extends Model {
     public function delete() {
       $this->objects()->delete();
       parent::delete();
     }
}

//also delete hierarchy in your object model with overriding delete method

class Object extends Model {
     public function delete(){
        $this->history()->delete();
        $this->subscriptions()->delete();
        parent::delete();
     }
}
```

Comment: Just to add information, this would be only good if you want to delete all related models every time parent model is deleted.

Comment: if its not the case then change the method name with some custom name for example deleteReferences() so it won't behave as default always delete method.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely to do in the reverse order.
If you removed the "parent", the "children", he can not find.
Try this.

```
$customers = Customer::find($clientId);
$customers->locations()->objects()->subscriptions()->delete();
$customers->locations()->objects()->history()->delete();
$customers->locations()->objects()->delete();
$customers->locations()->delete();
$customers->delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say

`$customers->locations()->delete()`

you are trying to delete a `Collection`. You should delete a `Model`.

So get all the *locations* using

`$locations = $customer->locations`

and then use a `foreach` loop to delete each `location`.

```
foreach($locations as $location) {
  $location->delete();
}
```

Similarly delete all other related models.